# How to keep circle in sync with div

Tags: html, css, position

In the attached image below, I want to recreate the "1" circle to the left of the profile box. I'm currently trying to use CSS positioning to get it like the image above, but whenever I shrink my computer screen, the circle doesn't move with the profile box. I'm not quite sure how to fix it. I've attached my code below the image.

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}

 
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
    
.Ranking{
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 4px;
    transition: background-color .25s linear .5s;
    font-family: "Decima";
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.Description{
    flex:1;
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 2/5;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="Ranking"></div>
        <div class="Name">One</div>
        <div class="Summary">Summary: <br>He really hits, with a LF fit</div>
        <div class="Level">Highest Level: A+ <br> Age: 21</div>
        <div class="Body">Height: 6'1" <br> Weight: 215 lbs</div>
        <div class="Profile"><img src="images/Dustin Harris.jfif"> </div>
        <div class="Description">Five</div>
      </div>
            
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example I want to create]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at two aspects: HTML markup and CSS basics. **TL;DR. See [this CodePen example](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/GROmZdQ) I put together for you.**

1. `position: absolute;` looks for the closest parent that has `position` value of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. If there's no parent that has such position value, the element will be positioned absolute against the body. In your example, `wrapper` (i.e. the immediate parent) doesn't have `position` defined, thus `Ranking` will be positioned outside your intended area.
2. As a matter of fact, you won't likely need `absolute` positioning here. `transform: translateX()` indeed is a good starter. Instead of `translateY()`, you could move it horizontally by `translateX()`.

Again, **see [this CodePen example](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/GROmZdQ) I put together for you.**

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS element called @media which will come helpful to you

```
@media screen (min-width: 800px) {
.container {
/* position and any property of the element according the small screen viewport*/
   }
}
```

800px is the screen size under which the screen become reactive.